# Как правильно образовать имя прилагательное?

Tags: словообразование

Как будет правильно:  Волковыский район или Волковысский район?

Answer (score 2):

**Волковыск** (белор. Ваўкавыск, польск. Wołkowysk) — город, расположенный в юго-западной части Гродненской области Белоруссии  на реке Россь, административный центр **Волковысского** района.

Схема образования относительного прилагательного: Волковыск ― Волковыс/ск/ий.

В этом случае происходит усечение К в основе перед суффиксом СК. Сравнить: Дамаск – дамасский, этруск – этрусский.

**Грамматическая справка**

Для основ существительных на СК возможно три разных решения

Форма 1. Одна буква С в относительном прилагательном **(полное наложение** суффикса СК на основу существительного)

Полное наложение суффикса СК на основу существительного делается для того, чтобы избежать стечения согласных  и преимущественно **в русских названиях:** Курск – курский, Томск – томский.

**Форма 2.**  Две буквы СС в относительном прилагательном (усечение основы существительного перед суффиксом СК)

Здесь происходит усечение буквы К в основе исходного  существительного   перед суффиксом СК **(обычно в иноязычных названиях**) и удвоение СС на стыке усеченной основы на С и суффикса СК: ***дамаск – дамасский, этруск – этрусский***.

Форма 3.  Одна буква С в относительном прилагательном (**нет наложения суффикса СК** на основу существительного)
   В некоторых случаях требуется сохранение основы исходного иноязычного существительного на СК: баски – баскский – нет наложения СК на основу.

**Примечание.** Правильность написания относительных прилагательных, образованных от иноязычных названий, **желательно проверять** по словарю или другим печатным источникам.

Answer (score 0):

волковыский-суффикс ск.суффикса сск-нет.

Comment: Зря не согласились с объяснением Sharon, посмотрите в документах, только решите, о каком языке идёт речь - русском или белорусском. Волковысский район - 
Ваўкавыскі раён. В русском языке от русских географических названий, оканчивающихся на -ск, прилагательные образуются без помощи суффикса -СК-, так происходит наложение двух -ск.
При образовании прилагательных от иноязычных географических названий, оканчивающихся на -к, буква -к опускается, а прилагательное пишется с -сс-

Comment: скажите пожалуйста эти правила об усечении действовали в 1948году.

Comment: Не могу сказать, по крайней мере нигде не видела указания на это  в изменениях правил, действовавших до принятия Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956 года. Видимо, ничего не менялось. У Вас есть сведения о другом написании в 1948 году?