# Удвоенная согласная в прилагательном: Дамасская сталь

Tags: орфография

Известен канонизированный святой Иоанн Дамаскин, город Дамаск в Сирии. Почему в словосочетании "Дамасская сталь" первое слово пишется с удвоенной согласной?

Comment: Вот здесь есть разъяснения: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447122/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5/447127#447127 (Как правильно образовать имя прилагательное?). Используйте поиск.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно образовать имя прилагательное?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447122/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)